# Why do I have a null value?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I've used this code in other places and it works fine. So why is it giving me a null value exception on the first AddWithValue command? I'm assuming that the others would have the same problem.

Here is the markup:

```
Select a Category:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="ORG_NAME" 
    DataValueField="ID">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORGANIZATIONS]"/>
<br />

Select an Organization:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName"
    DataValueField="ID">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT ID,SectionName FROM ORG_SECTIONS WHERE OrgID=@OrgID ">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategory"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            Name="ID" Type="String"
            DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<br />

Select an Attorney:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAtty" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" DataTextField="Expr1" DataValueField="ATTY_ID">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ATTY_ID, NAME & ' ' & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME AS Expr1 FROM ATTORNEYS ORDER BY NAME & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<br />
<br />


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="AddRec" />
```

And here is the code behind:

```
protected void AddRec(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)this.FindControl("ddlCategory");
    DropDownList ddlOrg = (DropDownList)this.FindControl("ddlOrg");
    DropDownList ddlAtty = (DropDownList)this.FindControl("ddlAtty");

    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\webvideos.mdb;";
    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO [Org_Sec_Atty] ([OrgID], [SecID], [AttyID]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrgID", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecID", ddlOrg.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttyID", ddlAtty.SelectedValue);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("ManageProfAffs.aspx");
}
```

There is one more field in my Org_Sec_Atty table (The ID field) which is auto incremented. Do I need to account somehow? Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you doing this inside a `gridview` or something?

Comment: I was thinking about using Formviews, but then I would have to put them around each ddl because they need to have different data sources. When I put the "this" in front of my declaration of ddl variables, I thought that was good. What do you think? It didn't give me any error.